# ob_get_contents stopped working for some unknown reason

Tags: php, xml, ob-get-contents

This script worked fine for a few weeks then stopped working for no reason.

`1.<?php`
`2.ob_start();`
`3.include "weather xml website";`
`4.$data=ob_get_contents();`
`5.ob_clean();`
`6.`
`7.$xmlFile = 'filelocation\weatherData.xml';`
`8.`
`9.`
`10.$fh = fopen($xmlFile, 'w') or die("can not create or open $xmlFile");`
`11.`
`12.fwrite($fh, $data);`
`13.fclose($fh);`
`14.?>`

I have used Google's and Msn's weather APIs and I can recieve the xml data fine by browsing, the file handler can create and edit the local xml. I had this script setup as a scheduled task to be run every 30 minutes.

Is there another method I should be using? caching? any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Has your server setup changed recently, specifically the `allow_url_*` ini settings (which should be `on`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, this code is *so* insecure. Including a remote file is highly dangerous. Your connection might be intercepted and thus an attacker could execute nearly arbitrary code on your server (including removing all files and stuff).

So, the problem is, that your hoster has set either [`allow_url_fopen` or `allow_url_include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) to `Off`. These options allow or disallow access to remote files using PHPs file functions and using the `include` statement.

What you want to do may be accomplished using far less code and making your code more secure:

```
file_put_contents('filelocation\weatherData.xml', file_get_contents('weather xml website'));
```

You could but some error checking in there, but that's basically all you need - and it prevents execution of arbitrary code by manipulating your connection!

If that still doesn't work probably not only `allow_url_include` is disabled, but `allow_url_fopen` is too. In this case you have no choice then to use [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, file_get_contents worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use PHPs [`file_get_contents()`-function](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to fetch your URL? You would not need the `ob_*`-functions then. Its also possible that your php.ini has some restrictions set that are related to including external URLs. I remember reading something about this in the comments of that file.
Additionally, you could simplify the file operations to a call to the [`file_put_contents()`-function](http://php.net/file_put_contents).

**EDIT:** As salathe pointed out, the php.ini options `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` are relevant to your problem. You should check your configuration for these.